# JasperReports Server - Partial results in crosstab

Tags: mysql, sql, jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I met a rather difficult problem to describe but the solution will be simple I think. Let's go!

I have a database with 4 tables:

> **Imputation:**
>
> Hours INT(11)
>
> ToBeBilled TINYINT(1)
>
> Day DATE
>
> Description VARCHAR(256)
>
> **Employee:**
>
> Name VARCHAR(50)
>
> Firstname VARCHAR(50)
>
> **Project:**
>
> Name VARCHAR(50)
>
> **TimeSheet:**
>
> Id INT(11)

I use these 4 tables to create the following crosstab in my report: http://framacalc.org/q3y7281ono

I use some parameters:

**Global_Liste_Projets**

```
Select
  Project.Name As Projet
From
  Project
Order By
  Projet
```

**Global_Liste_Noms**

```
Select
  Employee.Name As NOM,
  Employee.Firstname As Prenom
From
  Employee
Order By
  NOM,
  Prenom
```

Here is my SQL query :

```
SELECT
     Imputation.`Hours` AS Heures,
     Imputation.`ToBeBilled` AS Facturable,
     Imputation.`Day` AS Jours,
     Employee.`Name` AS NOM,
     Project.`Name` AS Projet,
     TimeSheet.`Id` AS TimeSheet_Id,
     Imputation.`Description` AS Commentaire,
     Employee.`Firstname` AS Prenom
FROM
     `Project` Project INNER JOIN `Imputation` Imputation ON Project.`Id` = Imputation.`Project_Id`
     INNER JOIN `TimeSheet` TimeSheet ON Imputation.`TimeSheet_Id` = TimeSheet.`Id`
     INNER JOIN `Employee` Employee ON TimeSheet.`Employee_Id` = Employee.`Id`
WHERE
     Imputation.Day BETWEEN $P{Global_Date_From}AND$P{Global_Date_To}
AND $X{ IN ,Project.`Name`,Global_Liste_Projets}
AND $X{ IN ,Employee.`Name`,Global_Liste_Noms}
ORDER BY
     Jours ASC,
     Projet ASC,
     NOM ASC
```

So, report generation is going well. But when I read my final report and there is more than one imputation filled in billable or non-billable for a specific date, there is only one imputation which appears! Instead there have several. When I do not *crosstab*, I see all imputations. So I think my problem is located in my *crosstab*?

My problem : oi61.tinypic.com/96jh3l.jpg and what I want : oi62.tinypic.com/10d7ebk.jpg. And a document in addition to try to explain slightly better my problem: framacalc.org/q3y7281ono.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem?

If I was not clear or missing information, do not hesitate :)

My complete XML :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="MyApp - TabCroise Projets" language="groovy" pageWidth="842" pageHeight="595" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="802" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5dcc996d-323f-4f19-834a-0b0c1ff4fbab">
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/dev/MyApp_-_TabCroise_Projets_1"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://jasperprod.mycompany.com:8080/jasperserver/services/repository"/>
    <style name="Crosstab Data Text" hAlign="Center"/>
    <style name="mycompanyStyleConditionnel">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProjetMeasure}.equals( "mycompany - Défaut" )]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#FF0000" backcolor="#FFAFAF" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <pen lineColor="#000000"/>
            </style>
        </conditionalStyle>
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProjetMeasure}.equals( "mycompany - Previsionnel" )]]></conditionExpression>
            <style forecolor="#FF0000" backcolor="#FFAFAF" isBlankWhenNull="false">
                <pen lineColor="#000000"/>
            </style>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <parameter name="Global_Date_From" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["01-01-2014"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="Global_Date_To" class="java.util.Date">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["12-31-2014"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="Global_Liste_Noms" class="java.util.Collection">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="Global_Liste_Projets" class="java.util.Collection">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT
     Imputation.`Hours` AS Heures,
     Imputation.`ToBeBilled` AS Facturable,
     Imputation.`Day` AS Jours,
     Employee.`Name` AS NOM,
     Project.`Name` AS Projet,
     TimeSheet.`Id` AS TimeSheet_Id,
     Imputation.`Description` AS Commentaire,
     Employee.`Firstname` AS Prenom
FROM
     `Project` Project INNER JOIN `Imputation` Imputation ON Project.`Id` = Imputation.`Project_Id`
     INNER JOIN `TimeSheet` TimeSheet ON Imputation.`TimeSheet_Id` = TimeSheet.`Id`
     INNER JOIN `Employee` Employee ON TimeSheet.`Employee_Id` = Employee.`Id`
WHERE
     Imputation.Day BETWEEN $P{Global_Date_From}AND$P{Global_Date_To}
AND $X{ IN ,Project.`Name`,Global_Liste_Projets}
AND $X{ IN ,Employee.`Name`,Global_Liste_Noms}
ORDER BY
     Jours ASC,
     Projet ASC,
     NOM ASC]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="Heures" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="Facturable" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    <field name="Jours" class="java.sql.Date"/>
    <field name="NOM" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Projet" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="TimeSheet_Id" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="Commentaire" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="Prenom" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch">
            <crosstab>
                <reportElement uuid="ae07f183-bdcd-4d36-a7bb-d1b9bd70d324" x="0" y="0" width="802" height="42"/>
                <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="2"/>
                <rowGroup name="NOM" width="119">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.String">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{NOM}+", "+$F{Prenom}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement uuid="123177dd-6b7b-44e6-a57f-1068dbef6078" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="119" height="50"/>
                                <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{NOM}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <rowGroup name="Facturable" width="96">
                    <bucket class="java.lang.Boolean">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{Facturable}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabRowHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true">
                                <reportElement uuid="ed64aa06-4e25-490e-b01f-abc509c87275" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="96" height="25"/>
                                <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Facturable : "+$V{Facturable}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement uuid="851b0620-71bd-4bf5-9b59-7b8010b0d931" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="25" width="96" height="25"/>
                                <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <text><![CDATA[Commentaire]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabRowHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalRowHeader>
                </rowGroup>
                <columnGroup name="Jours" height="30">
                    <bucket class="java.sql.Date">
                        <bucketExpression><![CDATA[$F{Jours}]]></bucketExpression>
                    </bucket>
                    <crosstabColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents backcolor="#F0F8FF" mode="Opaque">
                            <box>
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                            </box>
                            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy">
                                <reportElement uuid="3d7232fc-1dc1-4992-a0c9-987807cf5396" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="170" height="30"/>
                                <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                </box>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Jours}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </cellContents>
                    </crosstabColumnHeader>
                    <crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                        <cellContents/>
                    </crosstabTotalColumnHeader>
                </columnGroup>
                <measure name="ProjetMeasure" class="java.lang.String">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{Projet}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <measure name="ProjetCommentaire" class="java.lang.String">
                    <measureExpression><![CDATA[$F{Commentaire}]]></measureExpression>
                </measure>
                <crosstabCell width="170" height="50">
                    <cellContents>
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" pattern="" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement uuid="3e8d13d3-082e-49ff-9ef1-899959d21856" style="mycompanyStyleConditionnel" mode="Opaque" x="0" y="0" width="170" height="25" forecolor="#000000"/>
                            <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProjetMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                        <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                            <reportElement uuid="c8b997a0-ed98-489f-969f-5430ef550bcd" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="25" width="170" height="25"/>
                            <box topPadding="2" leftPadding="2" bottomPadding="2" rightPadding="2">
                                <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <topPen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                                <leftPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                                <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                                <rightPen lineWidth="0.0"/>
                            </box>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProjetCommentaire}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="25" rowTotalGroup="NOM">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#005FB3" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="596e5a5a-7a8f-40fe-80e1-fc6a94c6ddbd" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProjetMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell width="50" columnTotalGroup="Jours">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="64b759b2-b2cb-4769-8771-3b95451a4385" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProjetMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell rowTotalGroup="NOM" columnTotalGroup="Jours">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#005FB3" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="7eb03da8-5b6c-4f9f-a0db-22894bc6f523" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25" forecolor="#FFFFFF"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProjetMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell height="25" rowTotalGroup="Facturable">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="5f21a061-8bf6-4026-9f23-2c12653f0459" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProjetMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
                <crosstabCell rowTotalGroup="Facturable" columnTotalGroup="Jours">
                    <cellContents backcolor="#BFE1FF" mode="Opaque">
                        <box>
                            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                        </box>
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement uuid="a674fb2c-22f9-4c0c-87cc-0570b3430f68" style="Crosstab Data Text" x="0" y="0" width="50" height="25"/>
                            <textElement/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{ProjetMeasure}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </cellContents>
                </crosstabCell>
            </crosstab>
        </band>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: Can you illustrate the problem with help of screenshots?

Comment: Hi @Alex K, thank you to look at my problem because I'm starting to get a little crazy! Here are two screenshots: my problem : http://oi61.tinypic.com/96jh3l.jpg and what i want : http://oi62.tinypic.com/10d7ebk.jpg. 
And a document in addition to try to explain slightly better my problem: http://framacalc.org/q3y7281ono. When I read my final report and there is more than one imputation filled in billable or non-billable for a specific date, there is only one imputation which appears! Instead there have several. When I do not crosstab, I see all imputations. Crosstab problem ?

Comment: You didn't choose calculation function for measure in pivot table. Also concatenation is not in the list of available functions. You could use count to signal that there is more than one product.

Comment: @zoran-stipanicev, thank you for your answer. I just tried the Count function for measure in my pivot table. Indeed, this function returns me the number of projects, but it is not what i'm looking for. I want to display the names of these projects. I think you understood my goal ;), but it seems difficult to achieve.